# One line for looping with operation in python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I have optimization's problem with this for looping code:

My code like this:

```
total = 0
result = []
for test in testing:
    total += test.amount
    result.append({'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount})
```

i need to optimization the code to one line. i trying to change code to

```
total = 0 
result = [ {'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]
```

but i can't optimization for operation total

Thanks for help.

Comment: you need to describe your problem, not just say you have a problem. Be more specific, and tell us what you've tried

Comment: @shafeen i need to optimization the code to one line.
i trying to change code to 
total = 0
result = [ {'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]

but i can't optimization for operation total

Comment: what are you optimizing? what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean "optimize the code to one line", optimize in what sense?

Comment: One-line does not mean it is going to be optimal.

Comment: @eventHandler so, how to optimalization time processing about code?

Comment: You need to actually profile your code. Making a convoluted one-liner does not guarantee that your code will run faster, not at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can give me reference for optimized python code

Comment: A reference for what?

Comment: so what's `testing`? can write a bit of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I timed a couple variations for you to compare:

```
from functime import functime


class test_class:

    def __init__(self, amt=10, cat='A'):

        self.amount = amt
        self.category = cat


def func_1(testing):

    total = 0
    result = []
    for test in testing:
        total += test.amount
        result.append({'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount})

    return


def func_2(testing):

    result = [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]
    total = sum([i['value'] for i in result])

    return


def func_3(testing):

    result = [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]
    total = sum([test.amount for test in testing])

    return


def func_4(testing):

    result, totals = [], []
    for test in testing:
        totals.append(test.amount)
        result.append({'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount})

    total = sum(totals)

    return


def func_5(testing):

    result = [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]
    total = sum(test.amount for test in testing)

    return
```

I'll omit the calling of functions and print statements to save space:

```
--------------------
10 variables / 10000 iterations
--------------------

func_1: 0.0898552949414
func_2: 0.0572853889704
func_3: 0.0666673211647
func_4: 0.0676401432815
func_5: 0.0496420416234

--------------------
100 variables / 10000 iterations
--------------------

func_1: 0.371173584934
func_2: 0.310192364417
func_3: 0.330012053177
func_4: 0.53144825992
func_5: 0.377762000408

--------------------
1000 variables / 10000 iterations
--------------------

func_1: 3.60984478132
func_2: 3.05880308072
func_3: 3.29883265808
func_4: 4.98255212296
func_5: 3.36148284866
```

Comment: Interesting for your make example testing to give me

Comment: i trying pip install functime not found

Comment: hey @Evan I just updated my solution, how does it perform against the others?

Comment: @XeroSmith changing it to `sum([d['value'] for d in result])` would still improve the speed, like I mentioned in my comment earlier

Comment: @KomangSuryadana _functime_ is just a wrapper that I made for _timeit_

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting observations about your code:

incrementing `total` and building the `result` list are independent

both operations can be done quickly with `native python constructs`

```
result = [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount} for test in testing]
total = sum(d['value'] for d in result)
```

Editted to show that total is obtained by looping over a list of dicts and summing the `value` keys of each dict.

By the way , both lines are `optimised` python constructs.

Comment: Changing `sum(test.amount for _ in result)` to `sum([test.amount for _ in result])` will speed up the function. You can check my answer for timing results.

Comment: I see now that I didn't put these exact comparisons in my answer, but after going back to the code my comment is still true (.05s faster).

Comment: +1 for the completeness of your answer. I'm a bit suprised, I would have expected building the list before summing will incur some overhead.

Comment: @XeroSmith I think there might be some overhead to creating a generator, and stopping it with a StopIteration Exception which all happens if you don't create a list. Generators are great for reducing the amount of memory used, but it looks like they're not quite as efficient speed-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it all on one line, as you'd asked for. This is definitely not the way to go, but here are a couple of options:

```
def one_line():
    return [(a[0][0], a[1]) for a in [ (t, [tuple(t.append(t.pop()+test.amount) or te for te in [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount}])[0] for test in testing ]) for t in [[0]] ] ][0]

def one_line_alternative():
    return next(map(lambda a: (a[0].pop(),a[1]), [ (t, list(map(lambda test: next((t.append(t.pop()+test.amount)) or te for te in [{'category': test.category, 'value': test.amount}]), testing)) ) for t in [[0]] ]))
```

---

And here is a comparison to Evan Nowak fastest answer. I'm using 10 variables, 50000 iterations, and Evan Nowak's fastest optimization for 10 variables.

```
One Line:  2.8529339203163353
One Line Alternative:  2.859311107199918
Evan Nowak's fastest optimization:  2.3440381323539983
```

So, as expected, putting everything on one line is not a good idea.